# App isn't running in Genymotion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, genymotion

When I press run and choose the device (I'm using Genymotion) it says everything went right but nothing shows up.

I also get this error message.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the app first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your device go to `Settings > Application`.

Probably you have the app still installed for other users.

Try to find it and remove the app for all the users.

If the problem is this one you will find that app at the end of the list (in `Settings > Apps > All`)

All the apps marked as `Not installed` are still there, you can not install the same apps with Android Studio until they are there
[image]

NOTE: I haven't already had this problem personally, but I think if you click `Yes` in that dialog menu it should automatically remove your app/

If not, please try to follow above steps.

Hope it help